# Django: How to provide a category that changes at runtime in the urls.py?

Tags: django, url, django-views

I am trying to create a new URL level in my django-powered ecommerce site, meaning if a user is in `domain.com/category/foo/` I am trying to add the next level down, in which they click on some element in foo and wind up in `domain.com/category/foo/tag/bar/`.  To that end, I have created my urls.py line for detecting this, and I believe there is no problem here:

```
(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_tag', {
'template_name':'catalog/product_list.html'},'catalog_tag'),
```

Once the request has been mapped through the urls.py, I know it is going to need some variables from views.py in order for `get_adsolute_url` to do its thing, so I create the view:

```
def show_tag(request, 
                  tag_slug, 
                  template_name="catalog/product_list.html"):
    t = get_object_or_404(Tag, 
                          slug=tag_slug)
    products = t.product_set.all()
    page_title = t.name
    meta_keywords = t.meta_keywords
    meta_description = t.meta_description
    return render_to_response(template_name, 
                              locals(), 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And lastly, in my Tag model, I set up my `get_absolute_url` to fill the keyword arguments:

```
@models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_tag', (), { 'category_slug': self.slug, 'tag_slug': self.slug })
```

I made sure the category and tag I'm about to request exist, and then I type domain.com/category/foo/tag/bar and I receive a

```
TypeError at /category/foo/tag/bar/
show_tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_slug'
```

I believe I know where the error is, but I don't know how to solve it.  my `get_abolute_url` sets `'category_slug': self.slug` but that definition, as I said, lives in my Tag model.  My Category model lives in the same models.py, but how do I tell my `get_absolute_url` to go find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view `show_tag` must have a parameter to accept the `category_slug` which is not there right now:

```
def show_tag(request, 
    category_slug, tag_slug, 
    template_name="catalog/product_list.html")
```

Comment: Indeed that was the case.  I was so tunnel-visioned on "fixing" the `get_absolute_url` I just stopped looking everywhere else.  Thank you Aamir!

Comment: Well sometimes it happens, although the error is exactly pointing you where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, but I foolishly thought the error was occurring in the view because it was being provided the wrong information, not improperly configured to accept information.